# redis from python display in cli

Tags: redis, python-3.6

I am pushing data into `redis` from `python` like this:

```
ts  = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
if msg.field == 2:
    seq = [ts, 'ask', msg.price]
    r.rpush(contractTuple[0], *seq)
```

I expect the inserted data (`seq`) to be one object in `redis`. However, when I look at the data from the `reds-cli`the fields of the python list are on separate lines:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange ES 0 -13

406) "1523994426.496158"
407) "ask"
408) "2699.5"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Is this the way `redis-cli` displays data (strange if true imo), or am I pushing data into `redis` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#redis.StrictRedis.rpush:

> rpush(name, *values)
>
> ```
> Push values onto the tail of the list name
> ```

Redis doesn't have a concept of "objects". If you want these values to be grouped, you'll have to implement your own methods to (de)serialize them into strings.